# UI component library to display Microsoft Teams Messages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, user-interface, microsoft-teams

The App Studio within Teams has a few pre-built UI components. I would like to display a message from Teams as it would appear in the channel, but in a custom Tab.

Is there a library or functionality within https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/teams-js that will format an incoming message structure to HTML complete with things like mentions? Or is this something I have to build out from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Fluent UI React library by Microsoft [Link to Documentation](https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/components/chat/definition)

It has a chat component, that looks like it provides all the styling to match Teams which is nice. It does not (at first glance) look like you can simply give it a `chatMessage` object straight from Teams and have it displayed correctly.

Small wins.